# Can I use Java 7 with Eclipse 3.x?

Tags: java, eclipse, java-7

I am trying to config my eclipse (Helios) use jdk 7 to compile my code. I didn't install jdk 7 on my Windows XP. But I include all of the jdk contents with my project. It seems the solution provided in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638108/how-do-i-configure-eclipse-to-make-use-of-different-version-of-jdk) doesn't work. Compile java code needs JDK. the JRE is enough for running the compiled code. I think we need a way to configure the JDK to be used not just JRE. I tested with a JDK 7 new feature, String in switch, I can compile it in my batch file compile system but cannot use eclipse to compile it.

any idea?

Comment: Eclipse doesn't yet support JDK 1.7. Version 3.7.1 will do, but it's not out yet. If you're in a hurry, you can grab a stream build (which is sketchy but should work) from http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/eclipse3x.php .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I did to make Eclipse 3.x works with Java 7.

1. install Java 7 in another machine and then copy the JDK folder into my java application 3rdparty directory (so my machine still use Java 6);
2. download the Eclipse 3.7.1 from here: [eclipse 3.7.1](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/M20110831-1030/winPlatform.php#EclipseSDK)
3. configure Eclipse by following steps in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638108/how-do-i-configure-eclipse-to-make-use-of-different-version-of-jdk) (**select 1.7 in Compiler compliance level under the Java Compiler entry**);

At least I can use String in Switch now in Eclipse.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

> Compile java code needs JDK. the JRE is enough for running the
> compiled code.

- that is right

> "But I include all of the jdk contents with my project"

- Including those will not change eclipse's compiler behavior. Including files under project build path just makes those classes available for your application development/run-time (or as good as setting `CLASSPATH`)

Do these :

1 - Install required version of JDK

2 - Choose following menu - Window > Preferences > Java > Compiler - and you will see a drop down to choose the version you want to use.

3 - [Read this](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/preferences/java/ref-preferences-compiler.htm) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2638622/programming-java-7-in-eclipse) as well.

Good luck for being DBA after 5 yrs. Please consider working on your English as well (no offense please)