# Java 7 Syntax error

Tags: java-7

I have Java 7 running on my mac:

```
    System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.version")); // prints 1.7.0_05
```

**Project was created using**

[image]

**Project properties confirm, i am on Java 7**

[image]

Default system Java is 7

[image]

The following however results in syntax error

```
public static void main(String[] args) {    
    // Underscores in Numeric Litarals are ok here  
    int i = 11_234;
}
```

Eclipse is complaining with `Syntax error on token "_234", delete this token`

Comment: What happens on the commandline when you run  `javac -version`?

Comment: Comes back with `java version "1.7.0_05"`

Comment: What is the error message exactly?

Comment: In Eclipse `Syntax error on token "_234", delete this token`

Comment: Negative, this in fact is the first and only line in my Main class. Updated question

Comment: Looks like Eclipse is using a pre-Java7 compiler.  What do you see under Project | Properties | Java Compiler? The compiler is different from the JRE on the build path.

Comment: Hmm .. you are correct .. 1.7 is not there. Not even in the drop down list .. Why is that?

Comment: What version of Eclipse do you have?

Comment: I am running `Version: 3.6.2` Helios

Comment: Oh come on :) Downloading new version now. Thanks guys, you're awesome!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Eclipse's Project|Properties dialog, there two entities `Java Build Path` and `Java Compiler`.  The former will tell you what classes are used during the build, and you may have a Java 7 JRE listed there.  The latter, however, is the compiler that will be used to compile your code.  It is possible to have Eclipse use a Java 6 compiler even with a Java 7 JRE on the build path.

My guess is that you are using Helios, not Indigo.  See [Programming Java 7 in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2638622/programming-java-7-in-eclipse)

Comment: Thank you. Indeed this seems to be the case. I don't have 1.7 as an option on my Java Compiler section. How may i get it to appear there?

Comment: Are you using Helios or Indigo?

Comment: Downloading Juno now. Of all the things, updating Eclipse itself did not occur to me

Answer (score 5):

Make sure your version of Eclipse is 3.7.1 (this is Eclipse 3.7 Maintenance Build) or higher (see [JDT/Eclipse Java 7 Support](http://wiki.eclipse.org/JDT/Eclipse_Java_7_Support_%28BETA%29)) and that you have registered Java 7 with Eclipse (see [Eclipse and Java 7](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/gettingStarted/qs-with-java7.htm)).